# How to create a generic class of generics in dart?

Tags: dart, generics

I am trying to create a class **"CombinedResource"** that will contain 2 properties, each is of the type **"Resource"**.

Now the **Resource** class is as follows:

```
class Resource<T>{
  final T? data;
  Resource({this.data});
}
```

And the **CombinedResource** class is as follows:

```
class CombinedResource<T1 extends Resource<Ta>, T2 extends Resource<Tb>, Ta, Tb>
 {
  final T1? resourceA;
  final T2? resourceB;
  
  const CombinedResource._({
    this.resourceA,
    this.resourceB,
  });

  factory CombinedResource.create(
    Resource<Ta> rA,
    Resource<Tb> rB,
  ) =>
      CombinedResource._(
        resourceA: rA,
        resourceB: rB,
      );
}
```

---

Now, the **problem** is that the compiler is giving me an error on the factory method:

```
The argument type 'Resource<Ta>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'T1?'.
```

---

I tried changing the **CombinedResource** class to be as follows:

```
class CombinedResource<Ta,Tb>
{
  final Resource<Ta>? resourceA;
  final Resource<Tb>? resourceB;
  
  const CombinedResource._({
    this.resourceA,
    this.resourceB,
  });

  factory CombinedResource.create(
    Resource<Ta> rA,
    Resource<Tb> rB,
  ) =>
      CombinedResource._(
        resourceA: rA,
        resourceB: rB,
      );
}
```

---

This caused another **problem**, where I was unable to create an instance of CombinedResource:

```
 CombinedResource.create(
                  Resource(data:"sdc"), Resource(data:"sdc"));

  The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Resource<String>?'.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update:**
The second approach is working fine.

Comment: I can't reproduce any problem with your second version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt failed because you do:

```dart
  factory CombinedResource.create(
    Resource<Ta> rA,
    Resource<Tb> rB,
  ) =>
      CombinedResource._(
        resourceA: rA,
        resourceB: rB,
      );
```

but `CombinedResource._` expects arguments of type `T1` and `T2`.  You've specified that `T1` is derived *from* `Resource<Ta>`, which means that an instance of a `T1` must be an instance of a `Resource<Ta>`.  The reverse, however, is not true: not every `Resource<Ta>` is necessarily a `T1`.  Therefore a `Resource<Ta>` is not implicitly assignable to a `T1`. (Downcasts are potentially unsafe.)

I don't know why you inexplicably made your `factory` constructor use a different signature from your private constructor, but it'd work if you fixed it to use matching types:

```dart
  factory CombinedResource.create(
    T1 rA,
    T2 rB,
  ) =>
      CombinedResource._(
        resourceA: rA,
        resourceB: rB,
      );
```